# Is it possible to query dynamodb with fields other than hash and range keys

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using  boto to connect dynamodb  in python. I'm not seeing any proper tutorials for querying dynamodb. 
" What i need is that i need to fetch the content of the table where given name is  present in firstname or last name where first name and last name are the two fields using dynamodb "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB's [Query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Query.html) operation only allows you to specify the hash and range keys.  [Scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Scan.html) will let you provide other fields, but it isn't recommended for general application use.  I'm not familiar with boto, but if you want to further filter your results, you'll have to query if you can, then post-process the results in your application.  Otherwise, you'll have to scan, which would allow you to use the `CONTAINS` comparison on one field at a time.  You can't check both fields at the same time because the name would have to be found in both fields, not just one.  See the table entries called `ScanFilter`  on the Scan page for more information on what's possible.